# Flickr API for C# .NET always returns 100 pictures

Tags: c#, .net, flickr

The Flickr API for C# .NET always returns 100 pictures, no matter what page or what PerPage options I've entered. [An old thread in some Yahoo group lets me think this is an error, that never got fixed](http://www.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/4016/). Any ideas?

Comment: Seems the answer is on that very page: Anyways, the problem was that I had to set the per_page parameter in the list parameters and not the search parameters, sth which doesn't make sense(at least for me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved: Update your old [FlickrNet.dll](http://flickrnet.codeplex.com/), use the [example code](http://flickrnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ExampleGettingMoreThanOnePage&referringTitle=FAQ), then it will work.